# What are the default settings for grub customiser?

Tags: grub2

My grub's appearance settings were altered. Grub customiser can change it back to what it was but sadly there's no "default button". What are the default appearance settings?

Answer (score 1):

Note: *Original files which Grub Customizer will modify are moved to the `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts` folder, with the leading numeric designation removed.*

The `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts` and `/etc/grub.d/bin` folders, and any `*_proxy` files are only created if a Grub 2 script has to be modified. If only changes normally made to `/etc/default/grub` are invoked by Grub Customizer, the following won't be necessary.

**To restore the normal Grub 2 control of the boot menu:**

- Remove the `/etc/grub.d/bin folder`
- Move the contents of `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScritps` back to the `/etc/grub.d` folder.

  - Any files moved back need to be renamed to the original name.
  - linux back to 10_linux, os-prober back to 30_os-prober, etc.
- Remove the `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScipts` folder once it is empty.
- Check the settings in `/etc/default/grub` and make any desired changes (default kernel, timeout, etc).
- Run `sudo update-grub`.

*[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134)*

Comment: I have no folders in `/etc/grub.d` other than one named "backup". Thanks anyway